# Modify ticks without specifying tick length

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am making a `ListPlot`, in which the x-axis is the result of `AbsoluteTime`. I want the tick text to be human-readable by applying `DateString`, but don't want to mess with the automatic tick length. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: `DateListPlot`?

Comment: Don't know what you mean with tick length here, but if you're worried about the size of the label perhaps you could use `Rotate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you specify the tick mark length in your tick specifications tick marks are rendered with default length and style.

```
tickF = {#, DateString[#, {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", "/", "YearShort"}]} & /@ 
  AbsoluteTime /@ DateRange[##, {10, "Day"}] &;
```

Example data:

```
data = {{3368649600, 8}, {3369427200, 10}, {3370291200, 12}, {3370636800, 14}, 
  {3371673600, 15}, {3372537600, 20}};
```

If you have to use `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> Full,
 FrameTicks -> {tickF, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 GridLines -> {First /@ tickF[##] &, None}]
```

[image]

If not, `DateListPlot` is more convenient to use for your data structure:

```
DateListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, 
  FrameTicks -> {tickF, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]