# How to specify frame tick labels without modifying the Automatic tick marks?

Tags: graphics, ticks

I have the following:

```
Graphics[
  {
   EdgeForm[Opacity[0.5]],
   Opacity[0.75],
   ColorData[24, 6],
   Disk[{1, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}]
  },
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.5,
  ImagePadding -> 30
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to change the tick *labels* so that they occur only at whole-number values, and have no fractional part (i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`,... rather than `0.0`, `1.0`, `2.0`).

I want to keep everything else, including the tick *marks*, exactly as it is now.

Is there a way to do this that does not require me to build the unlabeled tick marks<sup>1</sup> from scratch?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The "unlabeled tick marks" would be: 1) all the minor ticks; 2) all the major ticks on the top and right edges of the frame; 3) the major ticks at (-0.5, 0.5) on the left edge, and at (0.5, -0.5) and (1.5, -0.5) on the bottom edge.</sup>

Comment: The way to do it without rebuilding the ticks from scratch would be to use `AbsoluteOptions` or `FullGraphics`, but those functions have never worked properly and have become more broken with each new version of _Mathematica_.

Comment: Related: [(6043)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6043/121),
[(6851)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6851/121),
[(19123)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19123/121),
[(76228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76228/121),
[(85339)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85339/121),
[(87095)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87095/121).  The bug that makes this more difficult: [(68937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will this work for you?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[FractionalPart[i] == 0., {i, Round@i, 0.02}, {i, ""}], {i, 
   Floor[min], Ceiling[max], 0.1}]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[0.5]], Opacity[0.75], ColorData[24, 6], 
  Disk[{1, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}]}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5, 
 ImagePadding -> 30,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {fticks, Automatic}}]
```

reference [How to increase the number of minor ticks in a plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/how-to-increase-the-number-of-minor-ticks-in-a-plot)

I do not know how to do it without calling custom function to build the tick labels.